# collection_radio_buttons: how do you wrap a tag around each radio button?

Tags: form-for, ruby-on-rails-5, collection-radio-buttons

`collection_radio_buttons()` is defined in the [rails 5.1 docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_radio_buttons) like this:

```
collection_radio_buttons(
    method, collection, 
    value_method, 
    text_method, 
    options = {}, 
    html_options = {}, &block
)
```

There is no explanation in the docs for what the `options` argument is.  The [simple_form docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm%2FFormBuilder%3Acollection_radio_buttons) say that there is an option called `item_wrapper_tag`.

I've been trying this:

```
<%= form_for(:an_article, url: "blah") do |f| %>

<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(
  :author_id, Author.all, 
  :id, 
  :name_with_initial,
  {item_wrapper_tag: :div}  #<=== HERE *****
) 
%>

<% end %>
```

I've tried every combination of symbols and strings for the key, `item_wrapper_tag`, and the value, `div`, and nothing succeeds in wrapping each radio button in a div.

Does anyone know if rails has a similar option as `item_wrapper_tag`?

Comment: Do you encounter any errors? If none, what does your form look like with your current code?

Comment: @Whooper, the generated html is radio buttons without divs around them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

```
<%= form_for(:an_article, url: "blah") do |f| %>

<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(
  :author_id, Author.all, 
  :id, 
  :name_with_initial,
) do |b|
%>

<div>
  <%= b.radio_button %>
  <%= b.label %>
</div>

<% end %>  #collection_radio_buttons do block
<% end %>  #form_for do block
```

`radio_button` and `label` are [builtin methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_radio_buttons) for the |b|uilder object:

> The argument passed to the block is a special kind of builder for this
>   collection, which has the ability to generate the label and radio
>   button for the current item in the collection... Using it, you can
>   change the label and radio button display order or even use the label
>   as wrapper...

Additional info:

```
collection_radio_buttons(object, method, 
                         collection, 
                         value_method, text_method, 
                         options={}, html_options={}, &block)

collection:    For each element in collection, a radio button and label tag is created.  
value_method:  Called on each element in collection, and the return value is assigned to 
               the value attribute of the radio button. 
object.method: If the return value of object.method is equal to the value attribute of a radio button,
               the radio button gets a checked="checked" attribute.
text_method:   Called on each element in collection, and the return value is used as 
               the text for the label tag. 
options:       Unknown purpose.
html_options:  Used to specify additional html attributes for the radio button, e.g. {class: 'group1'}
```

When you use `form_for()`, the `object` argument is the object encapsulated by f, so you omit the object argument:

```
f.collection_radio_buttons(method, 
                           collection, 
                           value_method, text_method, 
                           options={}, html_options={}, &block)
```

and `method` is called on this object:

```
             |
             V
form_for(:an_article, url: "blah") do |f|
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [gem simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for your forms. Then the code below should work already.

- Add `gem simple_form` in your `Gemfile`.
- Run `bundle install`
- Run `rails generate simple_form:install`

Then create a `simple_form` in your view that would look like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>

    <%= f.collection_radio_buttons( :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, item_wrapper_tag: :div) %>

<% end %>
```

Note: I just followed the form from the [collection_radio_buttons](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_radio_buttons) from APIDock.

This might do the trick. :)

Comment: No change.  I'm wondering if `item_wrapper_tag` is not rails.  I can't find any rails docs that explain the recognized options, and I got lost looking through the rails source code.

Comment: Do you just want to show the buttons with newlines?

Comment: No.  I want to wrap each radio button in a div.

Comment: @7stud I edited my solution. Please do give it a try. It worked with me and hopefully it also works with you. :)

Comment: I already know about simple_form.  I just find it hard to believe that a rails form helper forces you to have all your radio buttons on one line.

Comment: That's true! Though, there's a solution where you can have your buttons stacked (not on one line) but they won't be wrapped around in a div class.